# Raising Exception from ApiRouter does not run the exception handler, returns 500 internal server error instead. FAST API

Tags: python, http, error-handling, fastapi, starlette

I am raising a custom exception in a Fast API using an API Router added to a Fast API. I am defining the exception class and handler and adding them both using the following code. It was working before and now I am not quite sure what is the issue. The middleware got added so maybe that is the issue?

```
app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "*",    # Restrict these in the future?
]

app.include_router(memblock_router.router)
app.include_router(event_router.router)

app.add_exception_handler(UnauthorizedException, unauthorized_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(InvalidParameterException, invalid_parameter_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(DatabaseException, database_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(ElasticsearchException, elasticsearch_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(ParsingException, parsing_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(ForbiddenErrorMessage, forbidden_error_message_exception)
app.add_exception_handler(UnsupportedErrorMessage, unsupported_message)
app.add_exception_handler(RequestValidationError, validation_exception_handler)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

I am defining the exceptions and handlers like so

```
class UnauthorizedException(Exception):
    pass

def unauthorized_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: UnauthorizedException):
    print(str(traceback.format_exc()))
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                        content={"error": "unauthorized"},
                        headers=get_response_headers())
```

Comment: Add exception middleware. `app.add_middleware(ExceptionMiddleware, handlers=app.exception_handlers)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case the problem was related with imports. I had a project structure like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── app
│   ...
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── repositories
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── repository.py
└── requirements.txt
```

`repository.py` contained a class of an error I'd like to handle:

```py
# app/repositories/repository.py

class RepositoryError(Exception):
    pass
```

In `main.py` I registered a handler for this error:

```py
# app/main.py

...

from repositories.repository import RepositoryError


def get_application() -> FastAPI:
    application = FastAPI(title=PROJECT_NAME, debug=DEBUG, version=VERSION)

    ...

    application.add_exception_handler(RepositoryError, http500_error_handler)

    application.include_router(api_router)

    return application


app = get_application()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('app.main:app', host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, reload=True)
```

As you can see, I used a relative import `repositories.repository` instead of `app.repositories.repository`. When I dig deeper into the code where the appropriate error handler is being chosen I saw the following at `starlette/exceptions.py`:

[image: Imports in debugger]

An exception handler registered on the app was bound to the `repositories.repository.RepositoryError` class, but the caught exception was of the `app.repositories.repository.RepositoryError` class and these two classes didn't match. When I changed the import to `app.repositories.repository.RepositoryError` in my `main.py` everything worked ok.